# Make the text box go lower than image when window is resized

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I read one of the previous questions about how to make the text goes under the image, but it did't work just the way I want it.

I am trying to make a text box over an image. like this

[image: the image]

I am using wpbakery in wordpress, this is the css
And i don't know if it is a good idea to write the css like this. On tablets the box is right on the image, on mobile, the text will disappear.

The problem is that it goes right on the image when i resize the window.
How can I make the text goes lower than the image when the the window size is smaller than desktop.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: white;
  float: bottom;
  padding-left: ;
  padding-right: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://sijour.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/home-page.jpeg" alt="kids-clothes" style="width:50%;">

  <div class="text-block" style="margin-right:20%; margin-bottom:70px;">

    <p class="w3-margin" style="color: #9999;"> Kids clothes</p>
    <hr class="w3-margin">
    <h2 class="w3-margin"><b>Prens bebe</b></h2>
    <p class="w3-margin">Visit our Store online</p>
    <br>
    <div class="w3-button w3-round-large w3-pink w3-margin"> View more </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to set your image as a CSS background on the container, and just use padding and margins to position your text content.

Comment: i'm not pro. i don't really know how.